# SQL ORDER BY with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
SELECT Id, Request, BookingDate, BookingId FROM Table ORDER BY Request DESC, Date
```

If a row has a similar ForeignKeyId, I would like that to go in before the next ordered row like:

```
Request         Date  ForeignKeyId
Request3    01-Jun-11   56
Request2    03-Jun-11   89
NULL        03-Jun-11   89
Request1    05-Jun-11   11
NULL        20-Jul-11   57
```

I have been looking at RANK and OVER but haven't found a simple fix.

**EDIT**

I've edited above to show the actual fields and pasted data using the following query from Andomar's answer

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by BookingId order by Request DESC) rn 
        ,       Request, BookingDate, BookingID
        from    Table
        WHERE Date = '28 aug 11'
        ) G
order by
     rn   
,       Request DESC, BookingDate 

1   ffffff  23/01/2011 15:57    350821
1   ddddddd 10/01/2011 16:28    348856
1   ccccccc 13/09/2010 14:44    338120
1   aaaaaaaaaa  21/05/2011 20:21    364422
1   123 17/09/2010 16:32    339202
1       NULL    NULL
2   gggggg  08/12/2010 14:39    346634
2       NULL    NULL
2       17/09/2010 16:32    339202
2   NULL    10/04/2011 15:08    361066
2   NULL    02/05/2011 14:12    362619
2   NULL    11/06/2011 13:55    366082
3       NULL    NULL
3       16/10/2010 13:06    343023
3       22/10/2010 10:35    343479
3       30/04/2011 10:49    362435
```

The booking ID's 339202 should appear next to each other but don't

Comment: can't you just add the foreignKeyId to the end of your order by?

Comment: Can it be assumed that Request will be NULL whenever there's a duplicate of the ForeignKeyId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `partition` by ForeignKeyId, then sort each second or lower row below their "head".  With the "head" defined as the first row for that `ForeignKeyId`.  Example, sorting on `Request`:

```
; with  numbered as 
        (
        select  row_number() over (partition by ForeignKeyID order by Request) rn
        ,       *
        from @t
        )
select  *
from    numbered n1
order by
        (
        select  Request 
        from    numbered n2 
        where   n2.ForeignKeyID = n1.ForeignKeyID 
                and n2.rn = 1
        )
,       n1.Request
```

The subquery is required because SQL Server doesn't allow `row_number` in an `order by` clause.

Full example at [SE Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110419/).

Comment: I've edited my question before you edited your answer.  Will have a look at this.

Comment: This works, thank you.  Wish it was simpler as it's to go to a DevExpress grid for a custom sort but hey-ho.